# Can I make a ModalPopupExtender respond to tabbing cursor to control field?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My ModalPopupExtender works as expected if you click into the texbox named as it's control id.

```
    <cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
                                            targetcontrolid="txtCosCodeExpCode" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
                                            backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
                                        </cc1:modalpopupextender>
```

However, if you use the tab button, placing the cursor in the control field, the popup does not happen.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Calling this from the onfocus event of the text box (txtCosCodeExpCode) should work...

```
onfocus="$find('ModalPopupExtender1').show();"
```

Comment: That ever so nearly worked. I tried first adding your code: `onfocus="$find('ModalPopupExtender1').show();"`

Comment: That ever so nearly worked. I tried first adding your code: `onfocus="$find('ModalPopupExtender1').show();"`. That did not work, so I tried `<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopUp() {
        var id1 = window.$find('<%=ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>');
        id1.show();
    }
</script>`. This last version so nearly worked, but I am repeating the ascx control 10 times on a page. The OK button calls this - `  ModalPopupExtender1.Hide(); txtCosCodeExpCode.Text = ReturnCostCentreExpCode();`. The result (txtCosCodeExpCode) has come out on the wrong line!

Comment: Not sure I'm getting what you are saying. Is the model not shown when you tab into the textbox or are you having a problem setting the right text box when the ok button on the model is clicked?